Xcode Archive Fails for React Native Project – "Run custom shell script 'Bundle React Native code and images'"
I am working on a React Native project, and while building the project in Xcode works fine, for releasing the app to app store, and archiving it fails with the following error:
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

This error occurs in the "Run custom shell script 'Bundle React Native code and images'" phase.
Details:

Xcode Version: 16.0 (16A242d)
Node Version: /opt/homebrew/bin/node (Output from which node)
React Native Version: 0.74.3
macOS Version: 15.0.1 (24A348)

Build Phase Script:
Here’s the script currently in the "Bundle React Native code and images" phase:
set -e

WITH_ENVIRONMENT="$REACT_NATIVE_PATH/scripts/xcode/with-environment.sh"
REACT_NATIVE_XCODE="$REACT_NATIVE_PATH/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh"

/bin/sh -c "$WITH_ENVIRONMENT $REACT_NATIVE_XCODE"

What I’ve Tried:

Checked for the existence of with-environment.sh and react-native-xcode.sh in node_modules/react-native/scripts – The scripts folder is missing.

Reinstalled node_modules using npm install and yarn install – no change.

Verified that $REACT_NATIVE_PATH is empty when echoed.

Updated the script to directly use:
export NODE_BINARY=/opt/homebrew/bin/node
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh

– This didn’t solve the issue.

Cleaned the build folder in Xcode and removed DerivedData.

Ran pod install --repo-update in the ios directory.


Additional Information:

Error occurs only during the archive process, not during a regular build.
I checked the version-specific documentation and couldn't find a clear solution.

Question:

Has anyone encountered this issue where the scripts folder is missing in node_modules/react-native?
Is there a known fix or workaround to make the archive step succeed?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
I have tried multiple solutions that GPT suggested but nothing got fixed unfortunately :(
Alot of other stackoverflow answers suggested this fix but this was already fixed in my code by default:
update all the generated ...-frameworks.sh files to add the -f flag to the call to readlink. In other words, need to replace:
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
with
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"

I have the same exact issue right now on continuous integration only. It doesn't occur locally, just the CI. I was able to log it and the info that the react-native-xcode.sh script was not found. Why it is not found, well, that is a damn mystery.

I came across the same error too, here's how to actually debug the issue

Identify the failing script phase, which in my case is the "Bundle React Native code and images."
Expand the error log to view detailed steps. (click on hamburger menu to the right of script phase)

Scroll down to locate the specific error message.

in my case it was this Error: Unable to resolve module ../../../../assets/icons/BullseyeIcon
Fix any missing assets or incorrect paths in your code attempt to Archive the project again
Goodluck!
